# What is this construction in C and C++

Tags: c++, c

what kind of declaration is this in C **and** C++?

```
int (*array1)[10]
```

Also, after resolving this, since it is some kind of array, how to access those members?
If this is a function, which returns a pointer to an array of 10, pointer, than is it possible to declare it without parenthesis? What arguments does it take?

**EDIT:**
As you answered it is pointer to an array of 10 integers, what is the difference between these two?

```
int (*array1)[10]
int array1[10]
```

**EDIT:**
How to assign that pointer? I try

```
int array[10] __attribute__((used)) = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int (*array_ptr)[10] = array;
```

And it give error:

> cannot convert 'int*' to 'int (*)[10]' in initialization

Comment: It's a pointer to an array.

Comment: There is a websit that can tell you [See cdecl](http://cdecl.org/). It says *declare array1 as pointer to array 10 of int*.

Comment: This might help: http://www.cdecl.org/

Comment: Another link... http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: The second is an array with 10 elements of type `int*`, the first is a *pointer* to an array with 10 elements of type `int`.

Comment: Oops, I mean something different. Edited again.

Comment: The meaning is what I wrote in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

it is a **declaration** of *array1* as *pointer* to *array* 10 of *int*.

Access to it`s member is as usual, array1[0], array1[1] ...

Comment: If there was a trailing semicolon, it would be a **definition** too (unless there's an `extern` in there somewhere.